# how to extract specific words in negspacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

When I apply negspacy to  my sentence, I want negspacy to consider specific phrase as a single entity and give me the output for it.

```
import en_core_sci_lg
from negspacy.negation import Negex
nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load()

negex = Negex(nlp, language = "en_clinical_sensitive")
nlp.add_pipe(negex, last=True)

doc = nlp(""" patient has no signs of shortness of breath. """)

for word in doc.ents:
    print(word, word._.negex)
```

The output is -

```
patient False
shortness True
```

I want the output to be -

```
patient False
shortness of breath True
```

How can I consider phrases like "shortness of breath", "sore throat", "respiratory distress" as a single entity.

I have tried -

```
import en_core_sci_lg
from negspacy.negation import Negex
nlp = en_core_sci_lg.load()
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns =  [{"label": "ENTITY", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "shortness"}, {"LOWER": "of"}, {"LOWER": "breath"}]}]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
negex = Negex(nlp, language = "en_clinical")
nlp.add_pipe(negex, last=True)

doc = nlp("""patient has no signs of shortness of breath. """)

for word in doc.ents:
    print(word, word._.negex)
```

The output is still coming -

```
patient False
shortness True
```

What can I do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using scispacy model - en_core_sci_lg I used normal english model and got the desired results. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage

Answer (score 1):

You may be glad to know the solution to your problem is very simple. You are just missing the keyword argument `overwrite_ents=True` in the `EntityRuler` constructor, so the custom pattern you are adding is being overwritten by other entities. Just change:

```py
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
```

to

```py
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
```

Now, my output is:

```py
patient False
shortness of breath True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
nlp.add_pipe(ruler, before="ner")
```

This Should solve the issue that you have

Comment: haven't tried this solution but thanks for the answer.